# Unresolved reference: kotlinBuildProperties

Tags: java, android-studio-flamingo

im trying to implement library com.github.JetBrains:kotlin:v1.9.0 in app build.gradle but got time out error. so i downloaded the library and implement it as below:

implementation project(':kotlin-1.9.0')

unfortunately i hv got another error in build.gradle.kts as below:

e: F:\create apps\shop_my_mom\kotlin-1.9.0\build.gradle.kts:20:70: Unresolved reference: kotlinBuildProperties

here is the code and this code actually we can find it on github.

```
import org.gradle.crypto.checksum.Checksum
import org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.yarn.YarnLockMismatchReport


buildscript {
    // a workaround for kotlin compiler classpath in kotlin project: sometimes gradle substitutes
    // kotlin-stdlib external dependency with local project :kotlin-stdlib in kotlinCompilerClasspath configuration.
    // see also configureCompilerClasspath@
    val bootstrapCompilerClasspath by configurations.creating
    val bootstrapKotlinVersion = "1.9.0" // Change this to your desired Kotlin version
    dependencies {
        bootstrapCompilerClasspath(kotlin("compiler-embeddable", bootstrapKotlinVersion))

        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-build-gradle-plugin:${**kotlinBuildProperties**.buildGradlePluginVersion}") //error code line
    }

    val versionPropertiesFile = project.rootProject.projectDir.resolve("gradle/versions.properties")
    val versionProperties = java.util.Properties()
    versionPropertiesFile.inputStream().use { propInput ->
        versionProperties.load(propInput)
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            if (requested.group == "com.google.code.gson" && requested.name == "gson") {
                useVersion(versionProperties["versions.gson"] as String)
                because("Force using same gson version because of https://github.com/google/gson/pull/1991")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so i dont know where to start to solve it, where to find this kotlinbuildproperties, and im actually lost because im very new to android studio. thank you!